# Open or Start software keyboard in number or symbol mode

Tags: android, numbers, android-softkeyboard, textinput

I searched for a long time to get an answer and now it's time to ask my question ons stackoverflow.

I can not imagine that Android OS does not have the possibility to let the softkeyboard start in the number/symbol code and give the user the ability to switch back to letters?

i already tried this but without success:

in Code:

```
editTextHouseNumber.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
editTextHouseNumber.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

xmlLayoutFile:

```
android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
android:inputType="number|textCapCharacters"
android:inputType="number"
```

please help

Comment: Ben jij dit evert? ;)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I have understood your problem is that u want to have keyboard open with number type, as soon as your screen starts.
Try this that whether this is what you want.

```
<EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number">
    <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>
```

Comment: This way, you can not go back to character type (at least on nexus devices). I want to type symbols and characters

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this one.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html

> (EditorInfo.inputType & EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_MASK) can be one of many
>   different values, including:
>
> TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME TYPE_CLASS_PHONE TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
>
> - TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
> - TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME
> - TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
> - TYPE_CLASS_TEXT